# understanding testl in assembly language

Tags: c, assembly

Trying to understand some assembly language, but I am not sure if I am understanding it correctly

```
movl 8(%ebp),%eax // assign %eax to a variable, say var
testl %eax,%eax // test if var is > 0 or not. if var is > 0, jump to .L3
jge .L3
addl $15,%eax // add 15 to var
.L3:
sarl $4,%eax // shift var 4 to the right , which is the same as multiplying var by 16
```

given by above understanding, I wrote the following code

```
int function(int x){    
    int var = x;    
    if(var>0) {
        ret = ret * 16;
    }    
    ret = ret + 15;    
    return ret;        
}
```

however, my assembly code looks like the following

```
movl 8(%ebp), %ebp
movl %eax. %edx
sall $4, %edx
test1 %eax, %eax
cmovg %edx, %eax
addl $15, %eax
```

am I misunderstanding the original assembly code somewhere?

Edit: is there perhaps a loop involved?

Comment: The assembly and C code do different things, what did you expect?

Comment: It looks like you're missing an "else"

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the code continues with the shift even after the addition, and that `jge` also includes the equal case. Thus the code could look more like this:

```
int function(int x) {
    int ret = x;
    if (ret >= 0) goto skip_add;
    ret = ret + 15;
skip_add:
    ret = ret / 16;
    return ret;
}
```

Or, to avoid the `goto`, reverse the condition:

```
int function(int x) {
    int ret = x;
    if(ret < 0) {
        ret = ret + 15;
    }
    ret = ret / 16;
    return ret;
}
```

PS: shifting right is division, shifting left would be multiplication.